# How to do case insensitive search in ideavim (with / and ?)

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, webstorm, ideavim

Default search setting in IdeaVIM is case sensitive search.

For example, doing

```
/action
```

doesn't give results for `Action` but only `action`s

How to do case-insensitive search?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution for Vim works for IdeaVIM as well.
You can set the following setting:

```
:set ignorecase
```

to use case insensitive search every time. You can put it in `.ideavimrc` to have the setting persisted.

```
set ignorecase
```

If you want to switch to case sensitive search when your search keyword has a capital letter (which happens a lot), you can use `smartcase`

```
:set ignorecase smartcase
```

When you have this setting,

```
/action
```

would give results for `action`, `Action` etc and

```
/Action
```

would only give results for `Action`

If you want to switch these settings for one time uses, you can use `\c` as an escape character to trigger case insensitive search

```
/\caction
```

Similarly, using `\C` will do case sensitive search.

Comment: Note to turn on smartcase you have to set both of them, ie `set ignorecase smartcase`. setting `smartcase` alone does nothing.